# Add column based on value in other column

Tags: r

Make a new column that is binary based on if chance.of.admit > 0.5

chance.of.admit is a variable in the data frame

Would I need to loop over chance? How would I go about looping over change and adding a new column with 1's and 0's? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
df1$flag <- +(df1$chance.of.admit > 0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is:

```
df$binary <- ifelse(df$chance.of.admit>0.5, 1, 0)
```